# Stripe Connect and Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, stripe-payments

I'm trying to set up stripe connect with firebase functions. So far I have a connected account created when a new item gets added to the firestore DB with the following code.

```
 exports.createConnectedAccount = functions.firestore
  .document("dbitem/{dbitemId}")
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const account = await stripeClient.accounts.create({ type: "express" });

    return admin
      .firestore()
      .collection("connected_accounts")
      .doc(snap.id)
      .set({ account_id: account.id });
  });
```

Now the part i'm not understanding from the documentation is the following:

```
 const accountLink = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
  account: 'acct_1032D82eZvKYlo2C',
  refresh_url: 'https://example.com/reauth',
  return_url: 'https://example.com/return',
  type: 'account_onboarding',
});
```

how do I create the account links, and how to make the https request through firebase functions for the refresh and return urls.

Comment: I know nothing about Firebase, but from the Stripe perspective, the idea is you should call that `accountLinks.create` API, with the `account.id` of the account you just created.  You then make your client redirect to the `url` field of the link returned from the call(in a traditional server, this is simply that you return a 301 redirect to that URL to the client that called your backend route).

Comment: Thanks you helped me get to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I was looking at it all wrong.

the first part I had was correct where I created an account when an item was added to the database.

```
exports.createConnectedAccount = functions.firestore
      .document("dbitem/{dbitemId}")
      .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        const account = await stripeClient.accounts.create({ type: "express" });
    
        return admin
          .firestore()
          .collection("connected_accounts")
          .doc(snap.id)
          .set({ account_id: account.id });
      });
```

Next I created an endpoint in firebase that I triggered from the front end, and what this did was call accountLinks.create that returned a url that I then passed back to the front end

```
exports.refresh_url = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const body = JSON.parse(req.body);

  const { account_id } = body;
  await stripeClient.accountLinks
    .create({
      type: "account_onboarding",
      account: account_id,
      refresh_url:
        "change this tothe address to the firebase endpoint",
      return_url: "change this to the address for the firebase endpoint",
    })
    .then((accountLinks) => {
      res.json(accountLinks.url);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Could not get or createaccount links", err);
      res.status(400);
      res.send("could not get or create account links", err);
    });
});
```

Comment: What wil you use for refresh_url and return_url ?